# Mobilink error with Syncing to Production Oracle DB Options

Tags: synchronization, sqlanywhere, ora-00900, mobilink

Ok so here is the scenario.   We have two developers using the 
developer edition of Mobilink to sync to a consolidated Oracle 
DataBase using SqlAnywhere. 
The mobilink Version is Version 11.0.1.2331

Everything works fine in the two development environments.
One dev environment is Windows 7 x64 and Oracle 11g r1.  The other is xp x86 
and Oracle 10gr2.  Both work fine and are syncing with a replica of 
the production database(took a dump file from the production server). 
We are now in a beta state and are trying to set up the 
synchronization and it keeps failing.  The beta environment is using 
"SQL Anywhere MobiLink Server Version 11.0.1.2044" and is running on 
Windows 2003 x64.  Looking at the error log on the PDA and the Server 
confirms that the user is getting authenticated and that the 
synchronization is starting but it breaks at the same point each 
time.  Below are some additional details from the log.

I. 2009-12-04 13:30:38. <1> end_download_rows G_INV_LOCATION_DESC (no 
script)

I. 2009-12-04 13:30:38. <1> begin_download_deletes G_COMMENT_INFO (no 
script)

I. 2009-12-04 13:30:38. <1> download_delete_cursor G_COMMENT_INFO

```
                    --{ml_ignore}
```

I. 2009-12-04 13:30:38. <1> Translated SQL:

E. 2009-12-04 13:30:38. <1> [-10002] Consolidated database server or

ODBC error:  ODBC: [Sybase][iAnywhere Solutions - Oracle][Oracle]

ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

```
                     (ODBC State = 42000, Native error code = 900)
```

I. 2009-12-04 13:30:38. <1> Error Context:

I. 2009-12-04 13:30:38. <1> Remote ID: 62e3d800-e09d-11de-8000- 
fb73ff3a8e87

I. 2009-12-04 13:30:38. <1> User Name: bogus_user 
I. 2009-12-04 13:30:38. <1> Modified User Name: bogus_user 
I. 2009-12-04 13:30:38. <1> Transaction: download 
I. 2009-12-04 13:30:38. <1> Table Name: G_COMMENT_INFO 
I. 2009-12-04 13:30:38. <1> Script Version: bogus_user_scan

I. 2009-12-04 13:30:38. <1> Script:

```
                    --{ml_ignore}
```

I. 2009-12-04 13:30:38. <1> End of Error Context

I. 2009-12-04 13:30:38. <1> report_error  (no script) 
I. 2009-12-04 13:30:38. <1> report_odbc_error  (no script)

I also posted this question [here](http://groups.google.com/group/sybase.public.sqlanywhere.mobilink/browse_thread/thread/35100bd9837ce4e5#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you've run into a problem with --{ml_ignore} scripts that was fixed in v11.0.1 build 2260.

```
================(Build #2260  - Engineering Case #577142)================

The MobiLink server would not have skipped a script that was defined to be
ignored, if the script contained white space (spaces, tabs, and/or line-breaks)
before the special prefix, '--{ml_ignore}'.  This problem is fixed now.
```

I strongly suspect that if you upgrade your beta environment to the same build as your development environment, that this problem will go away.